# Android webview link not working in React Native

Tags: android-webview, react-native

I have implemented a `WebView` in React Native. The web page will have input fields and based on the data we entered it redirects to another page.

It is working fine in iOS but not in Android.
After clicking on a component in `WebView` I am able to see the url change and params of the url in iOS but in Android the url is not getting changed.

Any help please.

Comment: Are you running the build on simulator or on physical device?

Comment: Its giving issue in both Android emulator and Android device

But working in both iOS simulator and iOS device

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Good day! I have the same problem, did you find the solution?